# Saving MXDs to older version of ArcMap automatically?

Tags: arcgis-10.3, mxd, arcgis-10.6

I work at a company that has three computers running ArcMap, accessing the same files and databases. Two of them run version 10.3, but we just got a new computer with version 10.6. Saving a document in 10.6 means it can no longer be opened in 10.3, which is a problem. We need all three computers to be able to open the maps. What can we do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`File | Save A Copy...` allows you to choose what version of ArcMap to  use when saving. You may be able to add a shortcut to the Standard Toolbar, or if not you can set up a keyboard shortcut to this feature. To Customize the toolbar and/or keyboard shortcuts, click on the drop down arrow for the toolbar, or go to `Customize | Toolbars | Customize`.

[image: Standard Toolbar]

For a keyboard shortcut, go to Command tab, Keyboard, and then search for Save A Copy.  Type your desired keyboard shortcut in the lower left and click OK. (*Make sure the keyboard shortcut isn't going to replace any standard command like ctrl-C for copy.*)

[image: Customize dialog box]